# Google api: fragment not allowed

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, sugarcrm

I am trying to implement a google integration to a SugarCRM web application.

The flow is: User clicks on "use google" button, he is redirected to the google where he grants access to the application and then the google redirects him back to the application with received tokens.

The problem is, that the url of the application has to contain a # - fragment and google appears to have a problem with that.

```
Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Fragment not allowed:
https://{site_url}/#googleCallback/
```

Is there any way how to make this work? As far as I know, I cannot remove the # from the url in a harmless way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

so I have found a sub-optimal solution

instead of sending

```
https://{site_url}/#googleCallback/
```

I send

```
https://{site_url}/googleCallback/
```

and then let the .htaccess rewrite it for me

```
RewriteRule ^googleCallback/.* #googleCallback/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```